# Javascript OOP - calling a method from a different method of the same class

Tags: javascript, oop

I got this code:

```
class TestClass = function() {
    var methodOne = function(a, b) {
        return (a == b);
    }

    var methodTwo = function() {
        var elements = $('.element');

        elements.droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                if (!this.methodOne(ui.draggable.data('a'), ui.draggable.data('b'))) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

When running this, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.methodOne is not a function

Any ideas why?

Comment: It's because `this` is no longer the TestClass, but specifies the `this` on drop(event, ui), add var self = this; below var elements, and call self.methodOne()

Comment: So how can I call a method from there?

Comment: This is invalid use of the `class` keyword. It would throw `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`. Did you mean to use `var`/`let`/`const`?

Comment: Also, `methodTwo` already has access to `methodOne`, they are defined in the same scope, so you can just call it directly `methodOne()`, there's no need for `this.methodOne()`. Additionally, you need to research [how `this` gets bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in JS, depending on how a function is called, particularly when called as a constructor or an object method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse javascript with java. By javascript your class does not have private methods, so you cannot access these functions by using the `this` keyword.

You can do the following:

```
var TestClass = function() {
    var methodOne = function(a, b) {
        return (a == b);
    }

    var methodTwo = function() {
        var elements = $('.element');

        elements.droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                if (!methodOne(ui.draggable.data('a'), ui.draggable.data('b'))) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

but be aware that the `methodOne` and `methodTwo` variables don't have values outside the constructor, since they are local variables of the constructor function and not methods.

You can define methods by adding them to the prototype, e.g.:

```
TestClass = function() {};
TestClass.prototype = {
    constructor: TestClass,
    methodOne: function (){...},
    methodTwo: function (){...}
};
```

In this case the `this` keyword works if you call the `methodOne` from the `methodTwo`, but in your example you call it from a function defined in the `methodTwo`, so you have to use the `bind()` function to create a wrapper which sets the context by that function.

```
var TestClass = function() {
};
TestClass.prototype = {
    constructor: TestClass,
    methodOne: function(a, b) {
        return (a == b);
    },
    methodTwo: function() {
        var elements = $('.element');

        elements.droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                if (!this.methodOne(ui.draggable.data('a'), ui.draggable.data('b'))) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }
};
```

If you want to use ES6 classes instead of ES5, then the story is somewhat different, but you'll need a compiler e.g. babel, traceur, etc... As far as I know you cannot use the `class` keyword by ES5, so you should use `var` instead of that.

Answer (score 1):

Some points to raise:

1. The syntax of the ES6 classes is different.
2. You can use `bind` to fix the `this` object to the function assigned to `drop`.
3. Not related to the problem, but the `if` in that function really is unnecessary. You can just return the result of the boolean expression:

Code:

```
class TestClass {
    methodOne (a, b) {
        return (a == b);
    }

    methodTwo () {
        var elements = $('.element');

        elements.droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                return this.methodOne(ui.draggable.data('a'), ui.draggable.data('b'));
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Yepp, it is not clear whether he wants to use ES5 or ES6, the syntax is half way between them. Since he is using DOM and there is no babel tag on the question I guess he is trying to work with ES5 in the browser.